# radiusCorner and button

Tags: swift, button, radius

I have a little problem with my button.

My buttons are in a vertical stackview.

I wish to round only the corners of the top for my button #1.

[image: xcode]

My code :

```
extension UIButton {
     func roundedButton(){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.bounds
        mask.masksToBounds = true
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Use :

```
bouton1.roundedButton()
```

But the result is not good..

[image: prb button]

Why my button isn't complete ?
Do you have an idea ?

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is because you are calling that method in the wrong place.

Something that needs to get the correct rect value of a component needs to be called after the UI updates already rendered properly.

Add `view.setNeedsLayout()` and `view.layoutIfNeeded()` before calling `bouton1.roundedButton()` should fix your problem.